# Binding multiple fields to MenuFlyoutItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

In my Windows/Windows Phone Universal App, I have `ListView` with a `MenuFlyout` in my XAML layout. The `ListView` includes a list of people. Tapping on a list item reveals the flyout with options to email or call the person. Right now I am using the `Tag` property of the `MenuFlyoutItem` to hold the email address and phone number, but I also want to be able to get the name  of the person so I can send that when I open the email composer or phone dialer.

I am using the `Tag` element to store the basic information, but I want to access the name. How do I do this? Using extra properties? Somehow accessing the data binding of the parent object?

XAML:

```
<ListView
            x:Name="itemPositions"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem IsEnabled="{Binding IsFilled}" Tag="{Binding Email}" x:Name="sendEmail" Text="email" Click="sendEmail_Click" />
                        <MenuFlyoutItem IsEnabled="{Binding IsFilled}" Tag="{Binding Phone}" x:Name="sendCall" Text="call" Click="sendCall_Click" />
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding IsVerified, Converter={StaticResource BoolToInvisible}}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="Firebrick" Width="10" Height="70" />
                <Border Visibility="{Binding Required, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}">
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding IsFilled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToInvisible}}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Background="Gold" Width="10" Height="70" />
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,10" Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PositionName}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (element != null) FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
}

private async void sendEmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage mail = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    mail.Subject = "Leadsheet Position Assignment";
    mail.To.Add(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(element.Tag.ToString()));
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
}

private void sendCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(element.Tag.ToString(), "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thin you should be able to do this for example by checking the *DataContext* of clicked *Grid* or *MenuItem*:

```cs
private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Item yourItem = (sender as Grid).DataContext as Item;
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (element != null) FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
}

// you can also do the same in your menu items:

private async void sendEmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Item yourItem = (sender as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext as Item;
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage mail = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    mail.Subject = "Leadsheet Position Assignment";
    mail.To.Add(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(element.Tag.ToString()));
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
}
```

*Item* above is your ItemClass which you use in *Positions* set as ItemsSource. Once you have the clicked item, the rest should be easy. With this you also no longer need to bind in *Tag* property.